# Show that $B\ge A$ and $B\ge -A$ implies $B\ge |A|$ for self-dual matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-semidefinite, hermitian-matrices

EDIT:
It turns out, somewhat embarrassingly, that I misread the source exercise. The true claim is that

> $|A|$ is the smallest Hermitian transformation **that commutes with $A$** and satisfies $|A|\ge\pm A$.

Now, commuting Hermitian matrices are simultaneously diagonalizable, so the result is fairly immediate. I leave below my original post that led to an interesting characterization by user1551.

---

This is an exercise of Halmos (1958, §83, exc. 16(a)). Let $A$ be a self-dual matrix (meaning Hermitian in the complex case, symmetric in the real case). Write $A=\operatorname{diag}(\sigma_1, \ldots, \sigma_n)$ in some orthonormal basis. Then define
$$
|A| = \operatorname{diag}(|\sigma_1|, \ldots, |\sigma_n|).
$$
We can also say that $A=\sqrt{A^2}$ where $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is the unique positive semidefinite square root. The claim is:

> $|A|$ is the smallest Hermitian transformation (in the "definiteness" ordering of self-dual transformations) that is greater than both $A$ and $-A$.

I'm stuck on showing the minimality here. So let $B$ be self-dual with $B+A$ and $B-A$ both positive semidefinite, and I want to show that $B-|A|$ is positive semidefinite.

In the case where $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable, the result is straightforward by comparing eigenvalues. But I can't figure out how to extend from here to the general case.

Another strategy would be to use a previous exercise, where it shown that $0\le A\le B \implies \sqrt A\le\sqrt B$. With this it would be enough to show that $A\le B \implies A^2\le B^2$ and then take square roots. (To finish this reasoning, we also need $B\ge 0$, but that is fairly straightforward as well). I really feel like this should be true, but I'm stuck on it too.

Any hints appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simply false. E.g. by Sylvester’s criterion,
$$
B-A:=\pmatrix{2&\sqrt{2}\\ \sqrt{2}&2}-\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&-1}
=\pmatrix{1&\sqrt{2}\\ \sqrt{2}&3}\ge0
$$
and similarly $B+A\ge0$, but
$$
B-|A|=B-I=\pmatrix{1&\sqrt{2}\\ \sqrt{2}&1}
$$
is indefinite.

However, in general, $|A|$ is indeed the smallest in the sense that $B\ge \pm A\implies\|B\|_F\ge\big\|\,|A|\,\big\|_F$, and equality holds if and only if $B=|A|$.

It is also the smallest in the sense that if $|A|\ge B\ge\pm A$, we must have $B=|A|$. Clearly, $B$ is positive semidefinite because $B=\frac12(B+B)\ge\frac12(A+(-A))=0$. Therefore the condition $|A|\ge B$ implies that $\big\|\,|A|\,\big\|_F\ge\|B\|_F$. By the result in last paragraph, we must have $B=|A|$.

Alternatively, as $B\ge0$, the condition $|A|\ge B\ge\pm A$ implies that $\ker B=\ker A$. So, by considering the restrictions of $A$ and $B$ on $\operatorname{range}(A)=(\ker(A)\big)^\perp$, we may assume that $|A|$ and $B$ are positive definite. By replacing $B$ with $|A|^{-1/2}B|A|^{-1/2}$, we may further assume that $A=\pmatrix{I\\ &-I}$. Now partition $B$ accordingly as $\pmatrix{X&Y^\ast\\ Y&Z}$. From $I\ge \pmatrix{X&Y^\ast\\ Y&Z}\ge\pm\pmatrix{I\\ &-I}$, we obtain $X=I,\,Z=I$ and $Y=0$. Hence $B=|A|$.

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with partial orders. Do you think maybe Halmos could've meant something like: If $B\geq \pm A$ and $B\leq |A|$ then $B=|A|$? I wonder since he mentions explicitly in the "definiteness order".

Comment: @Jose27 Yes, that is true.

Comment: @user1551 Ohhh, okay, thank you! I've filled in most of the details from your answer, but: 1) how do conclude that $B\ge0$, $|A|\ge B\ge\pm A$ implies $\ker B=\ker A$? 2) On a somewhat embarrassing note, it turns out that I completely missed a specification of the original problem that $|A|$ is the smallest [...] **that commutes with $A$**. That makes the problem quite easy haha . I'm happy enough though, since it led to this other interesting characterization!

Comment: @Milten We have $\ker |A|=\ker A$ (diagonalise $A$ to see this). Therefore $Ax=0 \implies x^\ast |A|x=x^\ast Ax=0 \implies x^\ast Bx=0$, which in turn implies $Bx=0$, because $B$ is PSD. Hence $Ax=0\implies Bx=0$. For the converse, suppose $Bx=0$. Then $x^\ast Bx=0\ge\pm x^\ast Ax$. Therefore $x^\ast Ax=0$. If $y=Ax\ne0$, then for any positive $t$, we have $(x+ty)^\ast A(x+ty)=2t\|y\|^2+t^2y^\ast Ay$, while $(x+ty)^\ast B(x+ty)=t^2y^\ast By$. Therefore $(x+ty)^\ast A(x+ty)>(x+ty)^\ast B(x+ty)$ when $t$ is sufficiently small. This is a contradiction. Therefore $Ax$ must be zero.